# Filter function for label in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a WordPress site that uses WooCommerce. WooCommerce capitalizes every word in product attribute labels, which affects readability for long labels.

```
function wc_attribute_label( $name, $product = '' ) {
global $wpdb;
if ( taxonomy_is_product_attribute( $name ) ) {
    $name = wc_sanitize_taxonomy_name( str_replace( 'pa_', '', $name ) );
    $label = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT attribute_label FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies WHERE attribute_name = %s;", $name ) );
if ( ! $label ) {
    $label = ucfirst( $name );
    }
} elseif ( $product && ( $attributes = $product->get_attributes() ) && isset( $attributes[ sanitize_title( $name ) ]['name'] ) ) {
    // Attempt to get label from product, as entered by the user
    $label = $attributes[ sanitize_title( $name ) ]['name'];
} else {
    // Just format as best as we can
    $label = ucwords( str_replace( '-', ' ', $name ) );
}

return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', $label, $name, $product ); }
```

I need to change "ucwords" to "ucfirst" in this snippet from the above code:

```
$label = ucwords( str_replace( '-', ' ', $name ) );
```

I want to create a filter for this in my functions.php file. It seems like it should be easy, but I'm having a lot of difficulty. Any help would be much appreciated. This is what I have:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label' , 'custom_attribute_label' );
function custom_attribute_label( $label ) {
$label = ucfirst ( $label );
return ( $label ); }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the syntax of the add_filter.

Have rectified the code .Try this one now and let me know if that helps.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label' , 'custom_attribute_label',99,3 );

function custom_attribute_label( $label, $name, $product ) {
  $label = ucfirst ( $label );
  return ( $label ); 
}
```

Comment: This actually did not work, but I really appreciate your answer. It motivated me to learn more about filters. I ended up installing a plugin because I needed to add extra features to my WooCommerce order form. The plugin happened to resolve the label issue. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: This does work, just fine, even in 2021.